# Combining results after Union in Cypher Query (Neo4j)

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am working on *Graph Database* and wrote some *Cypher queries*.

**e.g**

First part of below query is for calculation of total no of likes of each person on a specific user's all posts and other parts of query are also similar.

**Query**

```
match a=(p:FaceBookPost{auther_id:"1"})-[hv:HAVE_LIKE]-(l:FacebookLike)
return COUNT(l.auther_id) as total, (l.auther_id) as authers order by total DESC

UNION ALL

match a=(p:FaceBookPost{auther_id:"1"})-[hv:HAVE_COMMENT]-(l:FacebookComment)
return COUNT(l.auther_id) as total, (l.auther_id) as authers order by total DESC

UNION ALL

match a=(i:InstagramPost{person_id:"1"})-[il:INSTAGRAM_LIKE]-(l:InstagramLike)
return COUNT(i.person_id) as total, (l.person_id) as authers order by total DESC

UNION ALL

match a=(i:InstagramPost{person_id:"1"})-[ic:INSTAGRAM_COMMENT]-(c:InstagramComment)
return COUNT(c.person_id) as total, (c.person_id) as authers order by total DESC
```

**Out put:**

```
   | total | authers
---+-------+---------
 1 |     4 | author 1
 2 |     3 | author 2
 3 |     1 | author 3
 4 |     2 | author 1
 5 |     1 | author 2
 6 |     1 | author 3
 . |     . | ........
 . |     . | ........
 . |     . | ........
```

**Required out put:**

```
   | total | authers
---+-------+---------
 1 |     6 | author 1
 2 |     4 | author 2
 3 |     2 | author 3
```

I have tried different ways and different queries for required out put.
But I could not get any solution.

Is there any way in Cypher to get required out put?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time there's no way to post-process results from `UNION`. There is, however, plans for that to be added - see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725#issuecomment-227973992.

However, in your example you could seek ways to avoid the need for `UNION` entirely. This would be clearer to understand, and more efficient.

Firstly, it's possible to combine some of those `MATCH` clauses immediately:

```
MATCH (:FaceBookPost{auther_id:"1"})-[:HAVE_LIKE|:HAVE_COMMENT]-(l)
RETURN COUNT(*) as total, (l.auther_id) as authers order by total DESC

UNION ALL

MATCH (:InstagramPost{person_id:"1"})-[:INSTAGRAM_LIKE|:INSTAGRAM_COMMENT]-(l)
RETURN COUNT(*) as total, (l.person_id) as authers order by total DESC
```

This is better, but still needs a `UNION ALL` because there are two different start points - one labeled `:FaceBookPost` and one `:InstagramPost`. If you could update your model so that both of these share an additional label, e.g. `:Post`, then you could reduce it to a single query.

Updating the model:

```
MATCH (p:FaceBookPost) SET p:Post;
MATCH (p:InstagramPost) SET p:Post;
```

Then querying:

```
MATCH (:Post{person_id:"1"})-[:HAVE_LIKE|:HAVE_COMMENT|:INSTAGRAM_LIKE|:INSTAGRAM_COMMENT]-(l)
RETURN COUNT(*) as total, (l.person_id) as authers order by total DESC
```

You may also want to share relationship types, for example replace `:HAVE_LIKE` and `:INSTAGRAM_LIKE` with just `:LIKED` (ditto replace the comment types with `:COMMENTED`).

Comment: Updating model as you told is not possible in my case.
I am also migrating data from RDMS to Graph DB.

Comment: I'd try to see if you can find a way to update your model after your migration from RDBMS, as it'll simplify all your queries. If you can't do that, you'll need to post-process the result of the union - until the linked github issue is resolved.

Comment: thanks for your response, but modeling is not possible in such a way in my case. because I have to add twitter data also.
which have totally different model.